# Lighting doesn't work in viewport render mode for "Rain_rig" file

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I'm working on Rain rig given by blender foundation, When I use the render mode everything looks like it's lit, but there are no lights, the world light is set to 0 strength and black. Nothing reacts to new lights. But when I go and render the scene everything works properly.[image]

and here's a video showing everything: https://youtu.be/OIE-BIJCxHw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have turned off the Lighting options
`[X]` *Scene Lights* and
`[X]` *Scene World*

Select the *Rendered* viewport shading mode (<kbd>Z</kbd>), then open the dropdown menu right next to the viewport shading mode icons and check the options. They must be checked to get the same result as in the final render (<kbd>F12</kbd>).

[image: viewport shadin options, scene lights and scene world]

If you have them unchecked no lights from the scene will be used and for the world, a built-in HDRI will be used. You can click the HDRI preview sphere to select another world lighting setup in this case.